# Python Mechanize - Way2Sms Sending Message

Tags: python, mechanize, cookielib, way2sms

I'm trying to send message using mechanize python with way2sms. While submitting sending. I got nothing.

[image]

br.submit() is not working here even though I edited msgLen = 135 (message = 'hello') characters.

I'm uploading tamper data screenshots and livehttp headers that might help you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to open the form and then we have to fixup in order to send submit the form. Directly submitting won't work here as it is using JavaScript.

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
message += ' ' * (140 - len(message))
br.form['mobile'] = mobile
br.form['message'] = message
br.form['msgLen'] = str(140)
br.form.method = 'POST'
sendurl = 'http://site23.way2sms.com/smstoss.action'
br.form.action = sendurl
br.form.fixup()
res = br.submit()
```

So, finally summing up all the code...!

```
import sys
import time
import os
import mechanize
import cookielib
from getpass import getpass

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
                  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
url = 'http://site23.way2sms.com/content/index.html?'
op = br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
stamp = "\n        +=======================================+\n        |..........Way2SMS Msg Tool v 1.........|\n        +---------------------------------------+\n        |#Author: 7H3 !N5|D3R                   |\n        |#Contact: www.fb.com/Gowtham95india    |\n        |#Date: 10/09/2014                      |\n        |#This tool is made for pentesting.     |\n        |#Changing the Description of this tool |\n        |Won't make you the coder ^_^ !!!       |\n        |#Respect Coderz Plz ^_^                |\n        |#I Take No Responsibilities For The    |\n        |  Use Of This Program !                |\n        +=======================================+\n        |.........  Way2SMS Automation .........|\n        +---------------------------------------+\n"
print stamp
username = raw_input('Mobile Number:')
password = getpass('Password:')
token = ''


def login():
    global username
    global token
    global password
    br.select_form(nr=1)
    br.form['username'] = username
    br.form['password'] = password
    br.submit()
    a = br.geturl()
    if username in br.geturl():
        print "[-] Login Failed."
        time.sleep(3)
        print "[-] Exiting Now..."
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system('clear')
        sys.exit()
        return False
    else:
        i = a.index('=')
        j = a.index('?')
        token = a[i + 1:j]
        return token


def send(mobile, message):
    smsurl = 'http://site23.way2sms.com/sendSMS?Token=' + token
    br.open(smsurl)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
                      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1'),
                     ('Referer', 'http://site25.way2sms.com/sendSMS?Token=' + token)]
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
    message += ' ' * (140 - len(message))
    br.form['mobile'] = mobile
    br.form['message'] = message
    br.form['msgLen'] = str(140)
    br.form.method = 'POST'
    sendurl = 'http://site23.way2sms.com/smstoss.action'
    br.form.action = sendurl
    br.form.fixup()
    res = br.submit()
    if 'status=0' in br.geturl():
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__  == '__main__':
    send(raw_input("Enter recpt: "),raw_input("Enter Msg: "))
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find this useful the following code i wrote  to  send sms which is working fine for me
full detailed solution is available on my blog http://rishabhroy.blogspot.in/2015/08/automate-sms-using-way2smspy.html 
Just replace username and password with your username and password.
    import urllib2

```
import cookielib

from getpass  import getpass
import sys

username= ''
passwd=''

message=raw_input("messge")
number=raw_input("number")

message="+".join(message.split(' '))

url= 'http://site21.way2sms.com/Login1.action'

data = 'username='+username+'&password='+passwd

cj =cookielib.CookieJar()
opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

opener.addheaders=[('User-Agent',"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")]


try:
        usock = opener.open(url,data)


except IOError:
    print "cannot connect "
    sys.exit(1)
jession_id=str(cj).split('~')[1].split(' ')[0]

print jession_id
 p= opener.open("http://site21.way2sms.com/ebrdg.action?id="+jession_id)

send_sms_url='http://site21.way2sms.com/smstoss.action'

send_sms_data= 'ssaction=ss&Token='+jession_id+'&mobile='+number+'&message='+message+'&msgLen='+str(140-len(message))
opener.addheaders=[('Referer','http://site21.way2sms.com/sendSms?Token='+jession_id)]

#opener.addheaders=[('Host','site21.way2sms.com')]
#try:
sms_sent_page = opener.open(send_sms_url,send_sms_data)
#except IOError as e :
#    print e
opener.open('http://site21.way2sms.com/smscofirm.action?SentMessage='+message+'&Token='+jession_id+'&status=0')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. BTW I got it.

Comment: did u implement it using mechanize ?

Comment: Yes, you can check here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043035/scraping-way2sms-with-mechanize/25751372#25751372